# JBPM - jbpm-server-7.35 reassignments not working

Tags: jbpm

On a user task, we configured reassignments with following info

```
Users:  Katy
Groups: HR
Expires At: 1m
```

at run time, I get a message:

> Please check that there is no group and user with same id

I tried removing HR and tried again, but no luck.

Please see the stacktrace below

> WorkflowRuntimeException: [changevalue.test:18 - Task:2] -- Organizational entity already exists with [UserImpl:'HR'] id, please check that there is no group and user with same id
>
> at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.processWorkItemHandler(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:175)
>   at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:146)
>   at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:203)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:408)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:389)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:358)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.java:44)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:412)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:372)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:307)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.workItemCompleted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:451)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.signalEvent(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:421)
>       at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.signalEvent(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:620)
>       at org.drools.persistence.jpa.processinstance.JPAWorkItemManager.completeWorkItem(JPAWorkItemManager.java:167)
>       at org.jbpm.process.workitem.rest.RESTWorkItemHandler.executeWorkItem(RESTWorkItemHandler.java:841)
>       ... 145 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Organizational entity already exists with [UserImpl:'HR'] id, please check that there is no group and user with same id
>       at org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.JPATaskPersistenceContext.persistOrgEntity(JPATaskPersistenceContext.java:255)
>       at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.persistIfNotExists(UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.java:153)
>       at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.addUserFromCallbackOperation(UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.java:141)
>       at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.doCallbackUserOperation(UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.java:104)
>       at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.doCallbackUserOperation(UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.java:97)
>       at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.doCallbackOperationForTaskDeadlines(UserGroupCallbackTaskCommand.java:419)
>       at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.AddTaskCommand.execute(AddTaskCommand.java:114)
>       at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.AddTaskCommand.execute(AddTaskCommand.java:56)

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug with `jbpm` reassignment feature. It tries to add the given users as groups and groups as users. Since 'HR' is an existing group, your scenario will give an error because of this reassignment bug (which is trying to add 'HR' as a user).

The issue is regarding bpmn file generation. In the process of file generation the user names are getting swapped with the group names.

```
<bpmn2:dataInputAssociation id="_pXn2EsUVEeq_vYStelyULQ">
    <bpmn2:targetRef>_77A0B1FE-F97B-4892-B916-1105512538F7_NotStartedReassignInputX</bpmn2:targetRef>
    <bpmn2:assignment id="_pXn2E8UVEeq_vYStelyULQ">
      <bpmn2:from xsi:type="bpmn2:tFormalExpression" id="_pXn2FMUVEeq_vYStelyULQ"><![CDATA[[users:HRGroup|groups:kris]@[2m]]]></bpmn2:from>
      <bpmn2:to xsi:type="bpmn2:tFormalExpression" id="_pXn2FcUVEeq_vYStelyULQ">_77A0B1FE-F97B-4892-B916-1105512538F7_NotStartedReassignInputX</bpmn2:to>
    </bpmn2:assignment>
</bpmn2:dataInputAssociation>
```

Kris should have been a user here and HR was supposed to be a group. To rectify it we can edit the bpmn file and reimport it in the project.

Comment: To complement you asnwer: here is the code from **jbpm-human-task-core-7.65.0-Final.jar**
org.jbpm.services.task.commands.ClaimTaskCommand#execute(Context cntxt)
...

userId is treated as groupId
`groupIds = doUserGroupCallbackOperation(userId, null, context);`

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it looks like you have a user name and group with the same name "HR" causing the conflict.

> I tried removing HR and tried again, but no luck.

From where did you remove "**HR**", did you remove the user with name "**HR**" from *application-user.properties*? If not try removing the user from the file.

If you still face the issue just cross-check if the entry is still there in the "OrganizationalEntity" table.